# Resampling using Rasterio's sum method

Tags: python, gdal

I have a raster file with 500m pixel resolution that I need to resample to a regular 0.25ºx0.25º grid. This resampling has to be done by aggregating all values in the raster file within each 0.25ºx0.25º shape.

I thought Rasterio provided a fairly good way to do this using the [sum warp resampling algorithm](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.enums.html#rasterio.enums.Resampling):

> Sum, compute the weighted sum of all non-NODATA contributing pixels. (GDAL >= 3.1)

This feature should be available from GDAL 3.1 onwards, as it states in the link provided:

> ‘sum’ is only supported in GDAL >= 3.1.

And, according to the webpage, the code for the sum resampling is 13:

> sum= 13

However, I have GDAL version 3.3.0 installed and when I do:

```
import rasterio as rio 
rio.enums.Resampling(13)
```

It returns:

```
ValueError: 13 is not a valid Resampling

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-035f41921f94> in <module>
      1 import rasterio as rio
----> 2 rio.enums.Resampling(13)

D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py in __call__(cls, value, names, module, qualname, type, start)
    313         """
    314         if names is None:  # simple value lookup
--> 315             return cls.__new__(cls, value)
    316         # otherwise, functional API: we're creating a new Enum type
    317         return cls._create_(value, names, module=module, qualname=qualname, type=type, start=start)

D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py in __new__(cls, value)
    567                         )
    568             exc.__context__ = ve_exc
--> 569             raise exc
    570 
    571     def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):

D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py in __new__(cls, value)
    551         try:
    552             exc = None
--> 553             result = cls._missing_(value)
    554         except Exception as e:
    555             exc = e

D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py in _missing_(cls, value)
    580     @classmethod
    581     def _missing_(cls, value):
--> 582         raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
    583 
    584     def __repr__(self):

ValueError: 13 is not a valid Resampling
```

It's worth noting that all resampling methods up to number 12 are working (nearest, bilinear, cubic, cubic_spline, lanczos, average, mode, gauss, max, min, med, q1, q3).

I am working on Windows 10 with Python 3.7.10 and Jupyter Notebooks.

Is this an issue with my installation of GDAL?

I would appreciate any help you could provide, as I have been searching on google for 2 days with no success. Thanks!